# Can Salesforce Suite handle many-to-many relationships with SF junction objects?

Tags: entities, crm

My salesforce implementation has a bunch of objects with many-to-many relationships, just as Drupal's node references are many-to-many. But in Salesforce I need to create junction objects to hold these relationships. I am not sure how to use Drupal's SalesforceSuite to traverse the junction objects in order to create the appropriate node/entity references.

Do I need to create a custom module to handle this?

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this?